# Is it possible to alias trait members in scala?

Tags: scala

Imagine I have a trait:

```
trait A {
    type Elem
    def list(e: Elem): List[Elem]
}
```

Is it possible somehow to create an object that extends this twice?

I know you can't inherit the same trait twice, but it could (in certain circumstances) be possible to have something like:

```
trait B extends A 

object Server extends A with B {
}
```

So, is it possible to somehow alias the members of trait `A` in `B`? E.g. so then in `Server` I could set `A.Elem = Int`, `B.Elem = String` and have scala use method overloading to call the appropriate `list` function?

My use case for this is I've built an HTTP endpoint that accepts a specific implementation of a form class. However, I want to allow it to handle several different form classes (e.g. `DetailedRegistration`, `SimpleRegistration`) and to reuse the relevant logic.

Comment: Pass in the `Elem` type via generics and it should work.

Comment: That makes a really messy interface though for my use case. I'll elaborate if that's the only solution.

Comment: Type member is like any other type/class/trait declaration member for the compiler, it cannot be aliases as you cannot alias an inherited `def`.